# Convert address into country

Tags: python-3.x

I have a panda table which has many countries as location based. The table is shown link this

```
Real Table  |After conversion 
Edinburgh, Scotland |UK
Nairobi, Kenya| Kenya
Manchester| UK
uk  |UK
Sirajganj   |Bangladesh
```

How to do that in python?

or coordinated to the country?

```
+05.0738+047.3288   to Somalia
+60.45148+022.26869 to Finland
+51.50853-000.12574 to United Kingdom
+33.24428-086.81638 to USA
+47.55839+007.57327 to Switzerland
```

Comment: Do you have some code which will let the community know what you have already tried/done ? The community can then provide suggestions/more ideas as to what you can do to achieve your desired goal - thanks

Comment: You probably need to call a third-party API for that, since there is no internal map that connects locations to countries.

Comment: I don't have any code right now. This dataset come from twitter location when it gives London and London, England two separate place. So I want to convert it with one country for every position.   I face this problem and can not find a solution. @Gagan. Do you know some API for this @terry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This program is solved using Yandex python.

```
import geocoder
g = geocoder.yandex([55.95, 37.96], method='reverse')
print(g.json)
g.json['country']
```